# Combine multiple words in custom meta search query

Tags: customization, search

I'm trying to create a custom search for my bookstore. I have two custom meta fields called vbs_author and vbs_publisher which hold the name of author and publisher of that product (book).

So far what I've got is:

```
$s = get_search_query(); 
$args = array(
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'meta_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                        array(
                            'key'     => 'vbs_author',
                            'value'   => $s,
                            'compare' => 'LIKE'
                        ),
                        array(
                            'key'     => 'vbs_publisher',
                            'value'   => $s,
                            'compare' => 'LIKE'
                        )
                )
            );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

When I search for an author `XYZ` or a publisher `ABC` individually, the results come fine. But when I combine an author and publisher in the same search, for example `XYZ ABC`, though they are values for `vbs_author` and `vbs_publisher` for the same product, the query returns 0 results.

I tried changing the relation to `AND` but it still didn't work...

Comment: When `$s = 'XYZ ABC';` it is not _LIKE_ 'XYZ' or 'ABC'.

Comment: Well, then is there anyway I can get results for LIKE 'XYZ' or 'ABC'?

Comment: You would need to split the words and add a separate meta query for each one, bu the performance will be garbage. WordPress search is really rudimentary, and adding a couple of LIKE comparisons to a meta query isn't going to get you very far. You need a proper search index. Something like [SearchWP](https://searchwp.com), [Algolia](https://community.algolia.com/wordpress/) or [ElasticPress](https://www.elasticpress.io).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the search query by white space and change 'compare' to 'IN' to be able to use meta values array:

```
<?php

$s = get_search_query();

$s_array = explode( ' ', $s ); // search query array

$args = array(
    'post_type'  = > 'product',
    'meta_query' = > array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => 'vbs_author',
            'value'   => $s_array, 
            'compare' => 'IN', // note the change
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'vbs_publisher',
            'value'   => $s_array,
            'compare' => 'IN', // note the change
        ),
    )
);
```

Maybe you'll need to remove duplicates after this.